# How can I redirect to my website when I click a button?

Tags: javascript, html

"SyntaxError: illegal character" at the second row.

```
document.getElementById('save').onclick = function(){
​      setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href = 'index.html';
         }, 5000);
    }​;
```

Comment: There is a hidden char at the start of your second line(+ before last semicolon). Copy this text into a plain text editor and you see it or directly remove it. It can also be seen when copying your text to FF's Dev tools Console (as a red dot).

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is almost perfect, the only problem is that you have an illegal character like the error is saying. I cleaned it in the question edit, if you copy and paste it now it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. i tried and it works

```js
document.getElementById('save').onclick = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
         }, 5000);
};
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="save">save</button>
</div>
```